# how to make small border in center of h1 text?

Tags: html, css

How to make small border in center of h1 text?

[image: Preview - What i need]

Comment: Tip: Use `span` within `h1`.

Comment: i not able to ask new question that saying wait for 3 days, please help me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a :pseudo-element.

```css
h1 span {
  position: relative;
  color: #F56B20;
}
h1 span:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 15%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #863C2F;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -7.5%;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Our Services</span></h1>
```

Comment: good answer to a broad question

Answer (score 3):

use the pseudo element `::after` to insert a blank element after the header, and style it to look like a border:

```css
#h_1{
    color:orange;
}
#h_1::after{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:25px;
    height:3px;
    background-color:maroon;
    margin-left:80px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="h_1">Our Services</h1>
```

Comment: good answer to a broad question